# Approaches for making a Web App query CSV file

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, csv, web-applications

I am looking at a CSV file hosted on an open government portal with daily updates, and would like to build a web app around it. Looking for the best approach, please advise. Current options I am looking at:

1. Reading CSV directly into a web app - seems to be a bad idea because it's a sizeable file over 70 Mb, likely will make it too long to load on the first user touch or even with each query
2. Schedule a task with something like AWS to read the file once a day and send its contents to a database such as Mongodb by either overwriting the db completely or pre-reading it and updating with newer entries, and then query this db from the web app

Am I missing any better approaches?

Comment: What about AWS Glue and Athena? refer this [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/extracting-salesforce-com-data-using-aws-glue-and-analyzing-with-amazon-athena/)

Comment: I will check it out @amitd, thank you